# Errors connecting to remote mysql db from wordpress due to IP address resolve issue

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, ipv6

I am hosting 2 droplets on digitalocean, and have IPV6 enabled on both.  The one droplet hosts one site, and the other hosts a wordpress installation.  I'd like to grab some data from that db, so I setup IPV6 networking on both droplets.

I've created a user for mysql at the IPV6 address of the WP droplet.  When I test connection from the terminal of the wp droplet using `mysql -u wordpressuser -h my:db:droplet:ipv6:address -P 3306 -p` it connects successfully, and I'm logged in.  all privileges are granted to that user.

On both droplets I've opened up port 3306.  If I try to do telnet my_ipv6 address it fails with "Temporary failure in name resolution"

When I look on the droplet that hosts the db, the mysql error log shows:

```
2020-10-12T14:58:25.711241Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.31-0ubuntu0.18.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
2020-10-12T15:02:47.746064Z 5 [Warning] IP address 'my:wp:droplet:ipv6:address' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
```

I figure someone will want to know what's in my conf file, so here we go:

```
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve

#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
# bind-address          = 127.0.0.001
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size         = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size         = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
```

How can I get this to connect successfully?  I just don't understand what I'm missing, and am a newbie on wordpress with an external db added.

Edited to add, I'm using:

- mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.31, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

In wordpress, I've tried connecting via php code from the ark theme:

```
$mydb = new wpdb('wordpressuser','my_password','my_external_db','my:external:ipv6:address');
$closed = $mydb->get_results("SELECT * from closed");
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($closed as $obj) :
   echo "<li>".$obj->Name."</li>";
endforeach;
echo "</ul>";
    enter code here
```

Comment: Seems like MySQL is trying to do a revere lookup and uses the IPv6 address as a hostname. Here's one solution: https://serverfault.com/a/341292

Comment: That didn't seem to solve my problem.  My log is now:

Comment: 2020-10-12T15:46:03.697463Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2020-10-12T15:46:03.697946Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-10-12T15:46:03.697971Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.

Comment: 2020-10-12T15:46:03.698027Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2020-10-12T15:46:03.698058Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2020-10-12T15:46:03.698062Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2020-10-12T15:46:03.698080Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-10-12T15:46:03.703383Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2020-10-12T15:46:03.703502Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.31-0ubuntu0.18.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)